# how to find of 2 lists of objects are equal in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have 2 lists of data:

```
data class PatientData(var patientID: String, var patientName:String, var patientPhone:String)

var list1: List<PatientData>?=null
var list2: List<PatientData>?=null
```

I need to determine if list1 is a duplicate of list2. One way of determining this is matching on patientID.

I have tried different ways such as zip and contentEquals but it did not work.

Comment: When would you consider the lists duplicates? Does the order of the lists need to be the same?

Comment: `if (list1.size == list2.size && list1.containsAll(list2) && list2.containsAll(list1)) true else false` :)

Comment: For that solution (or likely any) you need to make sure `equals()` and `hashcode()` are implemented correctly.

Comment: can you tell me how to implement equals and hashcode ?

Comment: Come to think of it, the 'data class' does that automatically I guess, so you are probably fine on that end. Then the solution from the previous comment should probably work. Even though the `if`-part can be left out. The expression in the parentheses should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data class is doing most of the comparison work for you out of the box, so it's just a case of doing some collection comparisons.

Like Animesh says, you can do a size check and a `containsAll` (if you know they're the same size you only need to do the `containsAll` check one way)

```
if (list1.size == list2.size && list1.containsAll(list2))
```

You can sort the lists and then directly compare them (since your classes don't implement `Comparable` we'll have to do it ourselves, `patientId` is a good choice assuming it's a unique value)

```
if (list1.sortedBy { it.patientID } == list2.sortedBy { patientID })
```

Or you might actually want to use a `Set` for this, if you don't want duplicate `PatientData` objects anyway - that will let you do nice set properties like unions and intersections, but for comparison purposes two sets are equal if they contain the same collection of items

```
if (set1 == set2)
```